# How to achieve no padding between two edittext's underlines

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-styles

Below is part of my current layout

```
<LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
                android:id="@+id/domainContainer"
                android:weightSum="1.0">
                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="44dp"
                    android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions"
                    android:id="@+id/txtDomain"
                    android:theme="@style/LoginEditText"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_globe"
                    android:hint="@string/domain"
                    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
                    android:textColorHint="#4F4F4F"
                    android:paddingRight="0dp"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|right" />
                <EditText
                    android:layout_weight="1.0"
                    android:layout_height="44dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                    android:inputType="none|textNoSuggestions"
                    android:id="@+id/txtHostname"
                    android:theme="@style/LoginEditText"
                    android:hint=".mydomain.com"
                    android:textColor="#9E9E9E"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    android:cursorVisible="false"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="6dip"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|left" />
            </LinearLayout>
```

I have zero padding between the text of the two edittexts, but how would I achieve **zero padding between the two underlines** of the two edittext views (i.e. **so it looks like one long line underline**).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to set a negative margin to bring the edittext widgets closer. Be careful as you could cause overlap though.

```
android:layout_marginRight="-8dp"
```

That said, I would discourage you from doing that as it can be confusing to the user to have 2 edittext views when it appears to be a single one.